# Create a JSON policy document using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am looking to create a JSON policy document and created a custom object in PowerShell which can be later converted to JSON.

```
function Add-ObjectContent {
  param(
      $InputObject,
      $Property,
      $Value
  )
  process{
      [array]$path = $Property -split "\."
      If ($Path.Count -gt 1) {
          $Obj = New-Object PSCustomObject
          Add-ObjectContent -InputObject $Obj -Property ($path[1..($path.count - 1)] -join ".") -Value $Value
      }
      else {
          $Obj = $Value
      }
        $InputObject | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $path[0] -Value $Obj
    }
}

$jsonPolicy = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
Add-ObjectContent -Property "properties.workLoadType" -InputObject $jsonPolicy -Value "SQLDataBase"
Add-ObjectContent -Property "properties.settings.timeZone" -InputObject $jsonPolicy -Value "Eastern Standard Time"
Add-ObjectContent -Property "properties.settings.isCompression" -InputObject $jsonPolicy -Value $true

$jsonPolicy | ConvertTo-JSON
```

It fails when it tries to add the same member again. Is there a way to add multiple values to the same member if exists?

Comment: Afraid there isn't a way to do that.  You could you break the entries up into separate objects.  Each time a new object is created, it to an array.  Export the array once all the objects have been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with the way you have that function coded, because you are always writing to the same path.

In writing a nested object, you have to pass in the fullpath of an existing path and append via your input object.

Example:

```
function Add-ObjectContent 
{
  param
  (
      $InputObject,
      $Property,
      $Value
  )

  process
  {
      [array]$path = $Property -split '\.'

      If ($Path.Count -gt 1) 
      {
          $Obj = New-Object PSCustomObject

            $AddObjectContentSplat = @{
                InputObject = $Obj
                Property    = ($path[1..($path.count - 1)] -join ".")
                Value       = $Value
            }
            Add-ObjectContent @AddObjectContentSplat
      }
      else 
      {
          $Obj = $Value
      }

        $InputObject | 
        Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $path[0] -Value $Obj
    }
}

$jsonPolicy = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

$ViewJson = {
    $jsonPolicy | 
    ConvertTo-JSON
}

&$ViewJson
# Results
<#
{}
#>

Add-ObjectContent -Property 'properties.workLoadType' -InputObject $jsonPolicy -Value 'SQLDataBase'

&$ViewJson
# Results
<#
{
  "properties": {
    "workLoadType": "SQLDataBase"
  }
}

#>
Add-ObjectContent -Property 'settings.timeZone' -InputObject $jsonPolicy.properties -Value 'Eastern Standard Time'

&$ViewJson
# Results
<#
{
  "properties": {
    "workLoadType": "SQLDataBase",
    "settings": {
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
  }
}
#>

Add-ObjectContent -Property 'isCompression' -InputObject $jsonPolicy.properties.settings -Value $true

&$ViewJson
# Results
<#
{
  "properties": {
    "workLoadType": "SQLDataBase",
    "settings": {
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
      "isCompression": true
    }
  }
}
#>
```

So, if you want to pass items as in your original, ...

```
Add-ObjectContent -Property "properties.workLoadType" -InputObject $jsonPolicy -Value "SQLDataBase"
```

... then you need to refactor that function to do the above or just leave your function as is and leverage the above approach.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much :)